# correct display in hoverinfo

Tags: r, plotly

I was wondering if I could get some help figuring out how to display the  quantity of each bar when hovering over them.
I made a bar chart to display shot frequency by shot type

```
 bones_count <- bones_22 %>%
  mutate( n = length(unique(typeAction))) %>%
  plot_ly( x = ~typeAction, y = ~n,
           hoverinfo = ~n)
  add_bars() %>%
  hide_guides()
```

If I convert to a tibble, n is 29 for all rows.
I manually checked the quantities in my chart and they are accurate but I would like the actual quantities to display instead of 29, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi - welcome to SO. I have edited the formatting of your post but it is going to be difficult to help without a reproducible example of your data using `dput()`. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a good idea to listen to the guidance from @SamR. You'll get faster answers that way.

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you're essentially looking for the value of y per bar to show in the hover content, correct? If that's what you wanted this should help.

You'll want to calculate these values before rendering your graph like I did with `group` and `mutate`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

data(animals, package = "ggfittext")

# only 6 rows, so double data to duplicate issue
ani = rbind(animals, animals) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  group_by(animal) %>% mutate(total = sum(mass)) # for the graph

plot_ly(ani, x = ~animal, y = ~mass, type = "bar",
        hovertext = ~total,
        hovertemplate = ("Total: %{hovertext}<extra></extra>"))
```

In this image, you see `Total: 10000`. In the data you'll see that there are two observations with the animal (well...fish) `herring.` Each of these observations indicates the mass is 5000.

[image]

If that's not what you meant or have questions, let me know.